# SQL Server not starting after hard reset

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

A server (Windows Server 2008 R2) in our office got hard reset and now SQL Server (2008 R2) is not starting. The Event log shows this error:

```
Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2009.100.1746.0, time stamp: 0x4cabc0fc
Faulting module name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2009.100.1746.0, time stamp: 0x4cabc0fc
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000007281
Faulting process id: 0x1c90
Faulting application start time: 0x01cba0335db216fb
Faulting application path: D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Report Id: 9b71acdd-0c26-11e0-918b-b8ac6f87ae6d
```

What would you recommend to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server. Seriously. This pionts to something being wrong. Corrupted file for the server (not database), memory issue, driver. Something.

I suggest opening a ticket with Microsoft PSS.

Why a hard reset on the server? As in: It is years that I had to make one, and that was a bad driver and / or bad memory. I would put a blame on a service not restarting on the need tomake a hard reset.

Meanwhile switch over to a backup server and load your backups there.

Comment: It was stupidly reset due to it not responding when attempting to RDC into it. Should have plugged a monitor/keyboard in to see if we could assess the problem from there or even remote shutdown it. Thanks for your feedback. Will have a look further tomorrow when back at work.